# Increase the space between x axis labels ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my ggplot and I need to adjust the spacing between x axis labels and make the plot larger. Please advise what is missing here? Trying to play with expand but without any luck:

```
ggplot(device_contacts_jaccard_android_ios, aes(x = factor(uuid_lev), y = j, fill = factor(android))) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap( ~ dt) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0, 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -90, hjust = 0))
```

[image]

I have checked other answers here, no one solved my issue, correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ggsave` or `pdf(...);...; dev.off()` to increase the output size of the image. Once you do that, the space between axis text labels should increase. You could also decrease the font using `element_text(size = 7)`, for example.

Note that in `ggsave(..., size, width)` are in inches, by default. Good starting points are `width = 8` and `height = 8`. If you want to change the units, try `ggsave(..., units = "cm")`.

Comment: thanks a lot for you answer but isn't it weird that in such powerful package I can't just the plot bigger? Should I use plotly instead?